# Keyframe animation not rendering

Tags: python, rendering, animation

I have made a keyframe animation ,through timeline the animation gets played , while rendering animation is not playing. Can anyone please help me out with python script?

Comment: Hi. Why do you want a Python script? If your animation isn't rendering there is some other issue. Please show screenshots of your file, explain your setup and, if necessary, upload your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I should have asked for python command instead of script.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110662/a-script-to-render-each-frame-as-image-not-render-animation-in-2-8