# frame_change_post/pre not working when Rendering Animation

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, mathematics

I've got this script file that works flawlessly in the viewport, but stops completely when I start rendering it as an Animation.

```
import bpy
import math

def my_handler(scene):
    print('testing') # this will be printed out 3 times each frame when rendering the animation, but once only in the viewport.
    #assigning variables to objects
    a=bpy.data.objects['EmptyTop']
    b=bpy.data.objects['EmptyRight']
    text=bpy.data.objects['TextRightSide']

    # formula for calculating distance
    distance=str(int(math.hypot(a.location.x - b.location.x, a.location.y - b.location.y)*10))
    text.data.body=distance

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

(my_handler) is refreshed every frame as I've tested it by printing a test text in it. However, the main problem is that it does not do anything with the next code (bpy.data.objects). I've tried to change (bpy.data) to (scene) as shown

```
import bpy
import math

def my_handler(scene):
    print('testing')
    #assigning variables to objects
    a=scene.objects['EmptyTop']
    b=scene.objects['EmptyRight']
    text=scene.objects['TextRightSide']

    # formula for calculating distance
    distance=str(int(math.hypot(a.location.x - b.location.x, a.location.y - b.location.y)*10))
    text.data.body=distance

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

Worked just fine in the viewport but gave me this message when rendering the it as An animation

```
(line 7, in my_handler
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "EmptyTop" not found')
```

Sooo, what should I do now to make it work?

Comment: Rendering as stills eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110662/a-script-to-render-each-frame-as-image-not-render-animation-in-2-8 will work with handler as is.

Comment: that worked for me. Thanks a lot!